# How can I see logs of the JSON post bodies sent by zapier to my CRM (Current RMS) via the Webhook zap during setup and testing?

Tags: json, api, zapier

I'm trying to send new users / new customres of my WooCommerce store into the rental management app current-rms.com as new Organisations / new contacts. Since Current RMS does not have a native Zap, I am trying to use the generic Webhook zap that Zapier maintains.

Specifically, I'd like to see the sent JSON body in Zapier posts that I make *during the setup* and testing of the Zap after clicking "Make a Zap!". The Task History is not detailed enough nor does it show hits during test and setup, since it's not live yet.

My trigger is a WooCommerce New Customer. This is working with Zapier WooCommerce Plugin and webhooks OK.
My action is the generic Zapier "Webhooks" Zap. The label "instant" appears next to it in the list at /app/zaps and it is "off".
One version uses JSON PAYLOAD as the action.
Another version uses CUSTOM PAYLOAD as the action.
Wrap request in array is YES.
Unflatten is YES.
My API key and subdomain are in the app URL as query strings and working OK.
When I hit test I get:

We had trouble sending your test through.
The app returned "Invalid JSON - missing or invalid entry for 'member'". This usually happens when your Zap is missing a required field or a field value isn't in a recognized format.
We made a request to api.current-rms.com and received (400) Bad Request.

Official docs are at: https://api.current-rms.com/doc#members-members-post

**Logging available at Current RMS side**
Part of the authentication of Current RMS involves knowing the domain of the account you are trying to access, in my case its `therockfactory` due to it being an account for my company https://therockfactory.net/

https://api.current-rms.com/api/v1/members?apikey=APIKEYCENSORED&subdomain=therockfactory
which returns the following when I use the correct API key:

{"webhook_logs":[],"meta":{"total_row_count":0,"row_count":0,"page":1,"per_page":20}}

**Maybe if I could see the actual hit that Zapier is posting to Current I could wrap my confused brain around it better? What me worry.**

The hit should look somewhat similar to this example, but I've not been able to locate it so far... (in Zapier)

```
Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Body
{
  "member": {
    "name": "Chris Bralton",
    "description": "Pictures and leaned back was strewn at one would rather more. People don't want of his own means of one hand! Unless it from our pioneer has he fallen tree but that ever stronger and a. Hid among us against the full of verdure through by my eyes.",
    "active": true,
    "bookable": false,
    "location_type": 0,
    "locale": "en-GB",
    "membership_type": "Contact",
    "lawful_basis_type_id": 10001,
    "sale_tax_class_id": 1,
    "purchase_tax_class_id": 1,
    "tag_list": [
      "[\"Red\", \"Blue\", \"Green\"]"
    ],
    "custom_fields": {},
    "membership": {},
    "primary_address": {
      "name": "Chris Branson",
      "street": "16 The Triangle",
      "postcode": "NG2 1AE",
      "city": "Nottingham",
      "county": "Nottinghamshire",
      "country_id": "1",
      "country_name": "United Kingdom",
      "type_id": 3001,
      "address_type_name": "Primary",
      "created_at": "2015-06-29T10:00:00.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-29T10:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "emails": [
      {
        "address": "abigail.parker@ggmail.co.uk",
        "type_id": 4001,
        "email_type_name": "Work",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "phones": [
      {
        "number": "+44 115 9793399",
        "type_id": 6001,
        "phone_type_name": "Work",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "links": [
      {
        "address": "www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=566828251",
        "type_id": 5002,
        "link_type_name": "Facebook",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "addresses": [
      {
        "name": "Chris Branson",
        "street": "16 The Triangle",
        "postcode": "NG2 1AE",
        "city": "Nottingham",
        "county": "Nottinghamshire",
        "country_id": "1",
        "country_name": "United Kingdom",
        "type_id": 3002,
        "address_type_name": "Billing",
        "created_at": "2017-06-29T10:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-29T10:30:00.000Z",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "service_stock_levels": [
      {
        "item_id": 10,
        "store_id": 1,
        "member_id": 1,
        "asset_number": "Chris Bralton",
        "serial_number": "",
        "location": "",
        "stock_type": 3,
        "stock_category": 60,
        "quantity_held": "1.0",
        "quantity_allocated": "0.0",
        "quantity_unavailable": "0.0",
        "quantity_on_order": "0.0",
        "starts_at": "",
        "ends_at": "",
        "icon": {
          "iconable_id": 85,
          "id": 1,
          "image_file_name": "abigail.jpeg",
          "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/current-rms-development/64a0ccd0-5fbd-012f-2201-60f847290680/icons/46/original/abigail.jpeg",
          "thumb_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/current-rms-development/64a0ccd0-5fbd-012f-2201-60f847290680/icons/46/thumb/abigail.jpeg",
          "created_at": "2015-06-29T10:00:00.000Z",
          "updated_at": "2015-06-29T10:30:00.000Z",
          "iconable_type": "StockLevel"
        },
        "custom_fields": {},
        "id": 487,
        "item_name": "Sound Engineer",
        "store_name": "Nottingham",
        "stock_type_name": "Service",
        "stock_category_name": "Resource"
      }
    ],
    "day_cost": "",
    "hour_cost": "",
    "distance_cost": "",
    "flat_rate_cost": "",
    "icon": {
      "image": ""
    },
    "child_members": [
      {
        "relatable_id": 317,
        "relatable_type": "Member",
        "related_id": 25,
        "related_type": "Member"
      }
    ],
    "parent_members": [
      {
        "relatable_id": 317,
        "relatable_type": "Member",
        "related_id": 25,
        "related_type": "Member"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE: After reading my chosen answer I was able to see what Zapier was sending:

```
[
    {
        "member[emails_attributes][0][address]": "test@test.co.nz",
        "member[membership_type]": "Organisation",
        "member[name]": "Testafari Testing"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send your webhook to a tool like this one to inspect the payloads that are being sent from anywhere on the internet: https://requestbin.com/

You can find more help in regards to using Webhooks by Zapier and other ideas on how you can troubleshoot issues stemming from its use: https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/help#inspect-the-requests

Comment: cheers that requestbin is awesome. now on to my next challenge: understanding unflatten and how to wrap my output with "member" like my example.